# Unet matchmaking limiting my game to 4 players in the middle of a live event

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine

we have a live event happening currently, yesterday it was working well connecting 7 players all good. This morning we booted it all up and for some reason we get no more than 4! Any ideas..?

We have tried the us server and the app one And we have a unity pro account so it should have a 200 ccu max

Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed by updating the build using new version of Unity 5.4.